# How to do these 2 things?

Tags: prestashop

I have 2 questions: do you know how I can disable the module that allows the user to choose the colour of the product? I don't need it and I would like to remove it. 
My second question is about the "Add to cart" yellow button.. I'd like to change its shape and colour but I can't find the way to do it. Do you know which line should I look for and in which file?

Answer (score 2):

1. This is not a module. Just do not use color attributes for your products and they will not appear
2. The "Add to Cart" button is styled in /themes/[YOUR_THEME]/css/product.css. In PrestaShop 1.5.6.2 row with the style rule is 338.